# ClassNotFoundException - Listener web app

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, listener, web.xml

Hello i have this error when run the application from Eclipse (Maven app, with spring and other dependencies). I have looked all over the internet but none answer solved my problem. My class "StartupListener" is in the right place, and i declared the listener in the web.xml.

```
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class com.playt.webapp.listener.StartupListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.playt.webapp.listener.StartupListener
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:532)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:514)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4854)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1258)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:716)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:221)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:213)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:611)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Can be a problem with Tomcat? Thanks in advance!!

StartupListenerClass:

```
    public class StartupListener implements ServletContextListener {
    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(StartupListener.class);

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        log.debug("Initializing context...");

        ServletContext context = event.getServletContext();

        // Orion starts Servlets before Listeners, so check if the config
        // object already exists
        Map<String, Object> config = (HashMap<String, Object>) context.getAttribute(Constants.CONFIG);

        if (config == null) {
            config = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        }

        if (context.getInitParameter(Constants.CSS_THEME) != null) {
            config.put(Constants.CSS_THEME, context.getInitParameter(Constants.CSS_THEME));
        }

        ApplicationContext ctx =
                WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(context);

        /*String[] beans = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        for (String bean : beans) {
            log.debug(bean);
        }*/


        PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = null;
        try {
            ProviderManager provider = (ProviderManager) ctx.getBean("org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0");
            for (Object o : provider.getProviders()) {
                AuthenticationProvider p = (AuthenticationProvider) o;
                if (p instanceof RememberMeAuthenticationProvider) {
                    config.put("rememberMeEnabled", Boolean.TRUE);
                } else if (ctx.getBean("passwordEncoder") != null) {
                    passwordEncoder = (PasswordEncoder) ctx.getBean("passwordEncoder");
                }
            }
        } catch (NoSuchBeanDefinitionException n) {
            log.debug("authenticationManager bean not found, assuming test and ignoring...");
            // ignore, should only happen when testing
        }

        context.setAttribute(Constants.CONFIG, config);

        // output the retrieved values for the Init and Context Parameters
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("Remember Me Enabled? " + config.get("rememberMeEnabled"));
            if (passwordEncoder != null) {
                log.debug("Password Encoder: " + passwordEncoder.getClass().getSimpleName());
            }
            log.debug("Populating drop-downs...");
        }

        setupContext(context);
    }

    public static void setupContext(ServletContext context) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(context);
        LookupManager mgr = (LookupManager) ctx.getBean("lookupManager");

        // get list of possible roles
        context.setAttribute(Constants.AVAILABLE_ROLES, mgr.getAllRoles());
        log.debug("Drop-down initialization complete [OK]");

        CompassGps compassGps = ctx.getBean(CompassGps.class);
        compassGps.index();
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
    }
  }
```

WEb.xml:

```
    <web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>appfuse</display-name>
    <distributable/>

    <!-- precompiled jsp mappings -->

    <!-- Define the default CSS Theme -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>csstheme</param-name>
        <param-value>simplicity</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- Define the basename for a resource bundle for I18N -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
        <param-value>ApplicationResources</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- Fallback locale if no bundles found for browser's preferred locale -->
    <!-- Force a single locale using param-name 'javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.locale' -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.fallbackLocale</param-name>
        <param-value>es</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- Context Configuration locations for Spring XML files -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:/applicationContext-resources.xml
            classpath:/applicationContext-dao.xml
            classpath:/applicationContext-service.xml
            classpath*:/applicationContext.xml
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext*.xml
            /WEB-INF/cxf-servlet.xml
            /WEB-INF/security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>exportFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <!-- GZipFilter has issues with XFire's service-listing servlet. -->
    <!-- http://issues.appfuse.org/browse/APF-863 -->
    <!-- And showing blank pages. http://issues.appfuse.org/browse/APF-1037 -->
    <!-- We recommend you configure gzipping in your servlet container.
         web server, or load balancer. -->
    <!--filter>
        <filter-name>gzipFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.filter.GzipFilter</filter-class>
    </filter-->
    <!--<filter>
        <filter-name>lazyLoadingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>-->
    <!-- Use "org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter" if you're using JPA -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>localeFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.playt.webapp.filter.LocaleFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>rewriteFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
        <!-- sets up log level (will be logged to context log)
            can be: TRACE, DEBUG, INFO (default), WARN, ERROR, FATAL, log4j, commons, sysout:{level} (ie, sysout:DEBUG)
            if you are having trouble using normal levels use sysout:DEBUG -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>logLevel</param-name>
            <param-value>commons</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <!-- set the amount of seconds the conf file will be checked for reload
            can be a valid integer (0 denotes check every time,
            -1 denotes no reload check, default -1) -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>confReloadCheckInterval</param-name>
            <param-value>-1</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>securityFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>targetBeanName</param-name>
            <param-value>springSecurityFilterChain</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>localeFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <!--filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>gzipFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping-->
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>rewriteFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>securityFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>exportFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.IntrospectorCleanupListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.playt.webapp.listener.StartupListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.playt.webapp.listener.UserCounterListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.playt.webapp.jsp.EscapeXmlELResolverListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>net.sf.navigator.menu.MenuContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/dwr/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/error.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>400</error-code>
        <location>/index.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>403</error-code>
        <location>/403.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/404.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Share your web.xml and Listener class

Comment: Post the `web.xml` file and `com.playt.webapp.listener.StartupListener`.

Comment: Hi, i edited my asnwer with the class and the web.xml

Comment: is the class that cannot be found inside your war WEB-INF/classes path?

Answer (score 0):

Hi thanks you to all for respond. All was right in the application, i resolved this undeploying the app from Tomcat Manager UI and Deploy again.

Cheers!